# Get an array with react native JS (even with stringify)

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

Hello everybody and thanks in advance to help me !!!!

I'm using react native, my state is an array when i tried to fetch the model >

```
[{"__v": 0, "_id": "5f44dcc0a3da3a3008a71e5d", "sport": {"_id": "5f44dcc0a3da3a3008a71e5e", "club": [Array]}}]
```

Instead of Array, i want the data from my database. we did a fetch to get the data. We are beginners, it's probably nothing but your help could save us :D

Also my code:

```
this.state = {
      sport: [{club: []}],
    };
  }

  getMesClubs = () => {
    const headers = new Headers({'Content-type': 'application/json'});
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: headers,
    };

    fetch('http://localhost:8080/inscription/sport', options)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(
        (data) => {
          this.setState({sport: JSON.stringify(data.sport)});
          console.log(data);
        },

        (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        },
      );
  };

  renderMesClubs = () => {
    return this.state.sport.map((element) => {
      return (
        (
          <View className="articles">
            <Text>{element.sport}</Text>
          </View>
        ),
        console.log(element.club)
      );
    });
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getMesClubs();
  }
```

and my model :

```
const ligue1 = new mongoose.Schema({
  club: [
    {
      nomClub: String,
      classement: String,
      dateMatch: String,
      classementDB: String,
    },
  ],
});
const sportSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  sport: ligue1,
});
```

Comment: So what is your question? What specific technical problem are you experiencing?

Comment: why are you using stringify when setting the state? `this.setState({sport: JSON.stringify(data.sport)});`

Comment: Why would you stringify your response, that's the cause of problem

Comment: We tryed to put the stringify because the state (in the console.log) can't be read (sport:{[object]}

Comment: then just stringify it when logging not when storing it

Comment: we delete the stringify, same problem  [{"__v": 0, "_id": "5f44dcc0a3da3a3008a71e5d", "sport": {"_id": "5f44dcc0a3da3a3008a71e5e", "club": [Array]}}]

Comment: thank you it's working now we just have to figure out how to render it :)